# UITabBarController wont show

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, uitabbarcontroller

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.main_tabs = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.viewController1 = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:NULL];
    self.viewController1.title = @"Home";
    UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController1];

    self.viewController2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:NULL];
    self.viewController2.title = @"About";
    UINavigationController *nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController2];


    self.tabs_array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:nav1,nav2, nil];
    self.main_tabs.viewControllers = self.tabs_array;
    [self.window addSubview:self.main_tabs.view];
    return YES;
}
```

This is the code from my appDelegate file. I've added a UITabBarController Programmatically but it won't show up at all. There's no errors or warnings that show up and nothing is logged. Any ideas? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    UITabBarController *main_tabs = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.viewController1 = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:NULL];
    self.viewController1.title = @"Home";
    UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController1];

    self.viewController2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:NULL];
    self.viewController2.title = @"About";
    UINavigationController *nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController2];

    main_tabs.viewControllers = @[ nav1, nav2 ];
    self.window.rootViewController = main_tabs;
    return YES;
}
```